# The formula for the optimal learning rate in the SGDClassifier in Scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gradient-descent

I cannot find the formula for the learning rate of the [SGDClassifier in Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#id1) when the `learning_rate='optimal'`, in the original C++ source code of this same function https://leon.bottou.org/projects/sgd

The formula is mentioned in [SGDClassifier in Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#id1):

[image: foo+bar]

Is this right formula used in the original `SGDClassifier` code, or did it change when ported to `Scikit-learn`?
Also what does t0 represent exactly (in the docs it's only mentioned that it was determined with a heuristic)?

Comment: This is the right formula. You can find it along with the initial t value in the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bac89c253b35a8f1a3827389fbee0f5bebcbc985/sklearn/linear_model/sgd_fast.pyx).

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Could you point out to the line in the source code? [Line679](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bac89c253b35a8f1a3827389fbee0f5bebcbc985/sklearn/linear_model/sgd_fast.pyx#L679) looks slightly different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets go through the source code and the formulas.

Sklearn states the following formula: `eta = 1/(alpha* (t+t_0))`. On the website of Leon Bottou we find the expression `eta = eta_0 / (1 + lambda eta_0 t)`.

Lets rewrite the latter formula a bit:

```
eta = eta_0 / (1 + lambda eta_0 t)
    = 1 / ( 1/eta_0 + lambda t )
    = 1 / ( lambda * ( 1/eta_0 *  1/lambda  + t)).
```

If now `lambda = alpha` and the `t_0` from sklearn is the same as `1/(eta_0*alpha)`, the formulas are the same. Lets now look into the source code: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/sgd_fast.pyx#L657

In line 657 we see that `optimal_init = 1.0 / (initial_eta0 * alpha)`. The `optimal_init` variable is only a different name for `t_0` from our formulas as we see in line 679: `eta = 1.0 / (alpha * (optimal_init + t - 1))`.

Hence, the formulas are the same.

Comment: It makes sense, thanks a lot. I wonder why the `-1` in `eta = 1.0 / (alpha * (optimal_init + t - 1))`, though. Another think observed from the source-code if I'm not wrong, `t0 = 1/(eta_0*alpha)` is dependant only on `alpha` since `eta0` itself depends on `alpha`.

Comment: The `t-1` part might be a counting thing and initialisation of `t`. I did not compare the python and c++ initialisation but there might be a `+-1` difference. The value `t_0` depends on `alpha` because it is scaled by it. Otherwise the initial learning rates are the same. The formulas are just slightly rewritten and hence the initial learning rate looks slightly different.

Comment: Just a last question, what does `t_0` represent exactly (I'm looking for a terminology)? I get it that having the time step `t` in the formula of the learning rate allows to decrease the latter each time. Is `t_0` used in the formula above mainly to regulate by how much the learning rate is decreased in each iteration?

Comment: You could maybe call it an "inverse, scaled initial learning rate". The larger `t_0`, the smaller the initial learning rate.